# Can Google Tag Manager (Preview Mode) Block Analytics Data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

When using Google Tag Manager I often want to test GA events that are using custom javascript or otherwise dynamically generated properties within their action/category etc created by GTM.

- Is there a way to use GTM preview mode and block it from sending that
  information/event into a GA account?
- I know I could filter out my IP address or such on the GA side, but
  is there any inherent way of telling GTM not to send this data?

My original guess was to delete the GA-ID variable of the even, but this is a required field.

Comment: Incase anyone is looking for similar functionality - I would recommend the use of DaVinci Tools - you can block your interactions with GA containers with a flick of a switch: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/da-vinci-tools/pekljbkpgnpphbkgjbfgiiclemodfpen?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good solution -  to create GA tracker for testing only. Then create variable (type "Google Analytics Settings") for your test GA number and use it for testing. When you will be ready to publish, just change GA Settings variable in tag.

Comment: As in create a new GA account for testing purposes only, and then use that GA ID for a new tracker variable within GTM?

Comment: @Joshberry-jenkins Yes. Create new tracker only for testing. Create in GTM 2 variables, for example - `GA` and `GA Testing`. And change these variables in tags as you need.